# Collation conflict in a union statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
select Regiune, CodUnitate, DataAprobare, UnitateaABR, ActivationDate, LocatieNoua
into #tb
from #mainunion 
where CanalVanzare in ('Sucursala', 'Alpha Point', 'Call Center', 'Broker', 'Real Estate')  

union all

select Regiune, CodUnitate, DataAprobare, UnitateaABR, ActivationDate, LocatieNoua 
from #addon
```

And I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" in UNION ALL operator occurring in SELECT statement column 2.

Can I get any help?

Comment: Your tables have inconsistent declarations. One CodUnitate is case sensitive, but the other is case insensitive. Fix that, and your query will run.

Comment: Alternatively add `COLLATE SomeCollationNameHere` after whichever colum is causing the problem